# Find all the numbers such that $\frac{2n-7}{5n-23}$ can't be reduced

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all the numbers such that $\displaystyle\frac{2n-7}{5n-23}$ can't be reduced

**My attempt:**

We want that:$\quad\gcd(2n-7,5n-23)=1$

that's equal to $\quad\gcd(2n-7,3n-16)\\
\quad=\gcd(2n-7,n-9)\\
\quad=\gcd(2n-7,11)$

So the answer is when $11\nmid 2n-7$

I am not sure about what I did, is it correct?

Comment: Yep, it is correct.

Comment: You may be expected to say that it can be reduced iff $2n\equiv 7\pmod{11}$, or equivalently $n\equiv 9\pmod{11}$, so can't be reduced iff $n\not\equiv 9\pmod{11}$.

Comment: Yes, thank you @AndréNicolas

Comment: Another way is to notice that $5(2n-7)-2(5n-23)=11$, so $\gcd(2n-7,5n-23)\mid 11$, so $\gcd(2n-7,5n-23)\in\{1,11\}$, so we have the equivalence $\gcd(2n-7,5n-23)=1\iff 11\nmid 2n-7$ (or equivalently $\gcd(2n-7,5n-23)=1\iff 11\nmid 5n-23$).

Answer (score 1):

We have \begin{align*}\gcd(2n-7,5n-23) &= \gcd(2n-7,n-9)\\ &= \gcd(11,n-9) = 1.\end{align*} Thus, $n \not \equiv 9 \pmod{11}$.