# Find all the numbers $a,b$ such that $\frac{2a-b}{2a+b}$ can't be reduced

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> Find all the numbers $a,b$ such that $\frac{2a-b}{2a+b}$ can't be reduced

*Attempt:*

For $a:$

$$\gcd(2a-b,2a+b)\\
=\gcd(2a-b,4a)\\
\boxed{\{a:4a\nmid2a-b\}}$$

For $b:$

$$\gcd(2a-b,2a+b)\\
=\gcd(2a-b,-2b)\\
\boxed{\{b:-2b\nmid2a-b\}}$$

I have a bad feeling about my answer

[Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804676/find-all-the-numbers-such-that-frac2n-75n-23-cant-be-reduced?rq=1)

Comment: I am just asking : Can we write gcd$(a,b)=-$gcd$(-a,b)$?

Comment: @Qwerty I don't think so, I think that $\gcd(a,b)>0$ for all $a,b\in \mathbb Z$

Comment: Okay.I got it .

Comment: @Qwerty As Error 404 says, $\gcd$ picks out the greatest positive common divisor (equivalently the greatest integer divisor) (or 0 in the case of $\gcd(0,0)$. Morally speaking it should perhaps return an ideal, but it is standard to think of ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$ as corresponding to the nonnegative integer generating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your attempts when you write, e.g.
$$
\quad \quad\gcd(2a-b,4a)
\\ \to \quad  \{a:4a\nmid2a-b\}
$$
because it is possible that $\gcd(2a-b,4a)$ is greater than $1$, so that the fraction reduces, even while simultaneously we do not have such a strong statement as $4a$ dividing $2a - b$. (e.g. $2a-b$ is even but not divisible by $4$ or by $a$.)

Instead, here's a useful fact:
$$
\gcd(xy,z) = 1 \quad\iff\quad \gcd(x,z) = 1 \text{ and } \gcd(y,z) = 1
$$
Therefore, we have that
\begin{align*}
\gcd(2a-b,4a) = 1
&\iff \gcd(2a-b,4) = 1 \text{ and } \gcd(2a-b,a) = 1 \\
&\iff b \text{ is odd,} \text{ and } \gcd(a,b) = 1. \\
\end{align*}

This gives you the condition you want: $a,b$ relatively prime and $b$ odd.

Answer (score 1):

If $b$ is even, $2|(2a-b,2a+b)$

So, $b$ must be odd.

Now, if integer $d>0$ divides both $2a-b, 2a+b$

$d$ must divide  $2a+b\pm(2a-b)=4a,2b$

So, $d$ must divide $(4a,2b)=2(2a,b)$

As $b$ is odd, $d$ must be odd & must divide $(2a,b)=(a,b)$ as $b$ is odd

So, if $(a,b)=1, d=1$

Can you take it from here?