# If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, prove that $a + 2b$ and $2a+b$ are also relatively prime or have a gcd of $3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, prove that $a + 2b$ and $2a+b$ are also relatively prime or have a $\gcd$ of $3$.

I'm very new to number theory so please don't assume I am familiar with some of the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $ \gcd(a + 2b, 2a + b) = \gcd(a + 2b, (2a + b) - 2(a + 2b)) = \gcd(a + 2b, -3b) $.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ By Cramer's rule (or elimination) we infer

$$ \begin{eqnarray} \ a\, +\, 2\ b &=& A\\ \\  2\ a\, +\, \ b &\ =\ & B\end{eqnarray}
\quad\Rightarrow\quad \begin{array}\  3 \ a\  = \, -A\, +\, 2\ B \\\\  3\ b\ =\ \  2\ A\, -\, \ B \end{array} $$

Hence, by the RHS system: $\ n\mid A,B\,\Rightarrow\,n\mid 3a,3b\,\Rightarrow\,n\mid (3a,3b) = 3(a,b) = 3$

**Remark** $\ $ In the same way [we can prove more generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1911456/242)

**Theorem**  $\ $ If $\rm\,(x,y)\overset{A}\mapsto (X,Y)\,$ is linear then $\: \rm\gcd(x,y)\mid \gcd(X,Y)\mid \Delta \gcd(x,y),\ \ \ \Delta := {\rm det}\, A$