# How to show that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\gcd(3^{n}+5^{n+1},3^{n+1}+5^{n})=2$ or $ 14$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ show that
$$
\gcd(3^{n}+5^{n+1},3^{n+1}+5^{n})=2\text{ or } 14.
$$

I tried induction but I got stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both odd, so their gcd is even. Moreover
\begin{align}
\gcd(3^n+5^{n+1},3^{n+1}+5^n)&=\gcd(3^n+5^{n+1}-5(3^{n+1}+5^n),3^{n+1}+5^n)\\
&=\gcd(3^n (1-3\cdot 5),3^{n+1}+5^n) \\
&=\gcd(3^n \cdot 14,3^{n+1}+5^n) \\
&=\gcd(14,3^{n+1}+5^n) 
\end{align}
divides $14$. So it can be only $2$ or $14$.

Comment: It cannot be $7$; as I wrote in the first line the gcd has to be even.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Use that for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ $\quad\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b-ka)$.

Comment: please remove also your comments, they are not useful to future readers, as it is :)

Answer (score 1):

It's $\,\overbrace{(3a\!+\!b,a\!+\!5b)}^{\Large\ \  a,b\ =\ 3^n,5^{n+1}}\!\mid \color{#c00}{14}(a,b)=14\,$ by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1911456/242), since $\ \begin{align} a&\mapsto\, 3a\!+b\\ b&\mapsto \ a\!+\!5b\end{align}\ $ has det $= 3(5)-1(1) = \color{#c00}{14}$

$a,b$ are odd so the gcd is even, so only the factors $2,14$ of $14$ are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g=\gcd(3^{n}+5^{n+1},3^{n+1}+5^{n})$.

Then $g\mid 3^{n}+5^{n+1}$ and $g\mid 3^{n+1}+5^{n}$ so $$g\mid 3(3^{n}+5^{n+1})-(3^{n+1}+5^{n})= 5^n\cdot 14$$

Since $5\nmid g$ we have $g\in\{1,2,7,14\}$. Since bot expressions are even we can rule out $1$ and $7$.