# Proving that $5^n+6^n$ and $5^{n+1}+6^{n+1}$ are coprime for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, coprime

I need to prove, using Bézout's identity, that $5^n+6^n$ and $5^{n+1}+6^{n+1}$ are coprime for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$. I know that if they are coprime there exist $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that:

$u(5^n+6^n)+v(5^{n+1}+6^{n+1})=1$,

but I am unsure on how to proceed from here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try it for small values of $n$ and see if there's a pattern

Answer (score 7):

Let $$a_n=5^n+6^n$$

Since $5,6$ are the roots of $$0=(x-5)(x-6)=x^2-11x+30$$  we deduce that the $a_n$ satisfy the recursion $$a_n=11a_{n-1}-30a_{n-2}\quad a_0=2\quad a_1=11$$

From this it is clear that if any $a_n,a_{n-1}$ have a common factor for any $n$, that factor also divides $a_{n-2}$. (Note:  we have $\gcd(a_n,30)=1$ for all $n$ so we can disregard the coefficient of the $a_{n-2}$ term). Since $a_0,a_1$ have no common factors, we are done.

Comment: With a little more effort, you can also deduce a Bezout relation, which seems to be more what the OP is looking for.

Comment: It is clear that a common factor of $a_n,a_{n-1}$ also divides $30a_{n-2}$. How do you get rid of $30$?

Comment: @lhf It follows from $a_n=5^n+6^n$ that $a_n$ is coprime to $5$ and $6$

Comment: @lhf  Yes, I should have stressed that we know that no common factor could be a divisor of $30$.  I'll edit to point that out.

Answer (score 5):

You want Bezout's identity? Here is one.

$(6^n,5^n)=1$,so integers $s,t$ exist such that $s*6^n+t*5^n=1$.

Then we have $(s-t)(6^{n+1}+5^{n+1})+(-5s+6t)(6^n+5^n)=1$

Comment: Note that this equation arises from the (extended) Euclidean gcd algorithm - as I hinted in my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque Actually I tried to find the exact value of $s$ and $t$, but failed. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: One way is to expand $\, (6-5)^{\large 2n}\,$ using the Binomial Theorem.

Comment: @BillDubuque That is a great idea.

Comment: It's a common Bezout-based proof of $\,(a,b)=1\,\Rightarrow\,(a^j,b^k) = 1\ \ $

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $ $ By Euclid: $(a\!+\!b,\,5a\!+\!6b) = (a\!+\!b,\,5a\!+\!6b-5(a\!+\!b)) = (a\!+\!b,\,b) = (a,b)$

Comment: Oh cool this can be generalized with $m$ and $m+1$ so $(a\!+\!b,\,ma\!+\!(m\!+\!1)b) = (a\!+\!b,\,ma\!+\!(m\!+\!1)b-m(a\!+\!b)) = (a\!+\!b,\,b) = (a,b)$ 

$m,n,p\in\Bbb{N}|n\neq p,m>1$ 

$m^n\!+\!(m\!+\!1)^n$ is coprime to $m^p\!+\!(m\!+\!1)^p$

Comment: @quantus14 In fact it can be generalized further [as here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1911456/242)

Comment: @Bill_Dubuque So if $a,b,m,s,t,u,v\in\Bbb{N}|su-tv=\pm 1$ and $s,t,u,v>1$ 

then $(sa+tb,ua+vb)=(a,b)\Rightarrow s^m+t^m$ is coprime to $u^m+v^m$?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it as, let $d_n=(5^n+6^n,5^{n+1}+6^{n+1})$. Since $d_n\mid 5^n+6^n$, $d_n\mid 5^{n+1}+5\cdot 6^n$, hence, $d_n\mid 5^{n+1}+6^{n+1}-(5^{n+1}+5\cdot 6^n)=6^n$. If $p\mid d_n$ a prime, then $p\in\{2,3\}$. Now, run the same argument, this time noticing $d_n\mid (6\cdot 5^n+6^{n+1})-(5^{n+1}+6^{n+1})=5^n$, hence, any $p\mid d_n$ satisfy $p\in\{5\}$, contradiction.