# GCD (a,b) =1 prove GCD ( (a+b), (a-b) ) = 1 or 2

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

if GCD of $(a, b) = 1$, prove that GCD $(a+b, a-b) = 1$ or $2 .$
The proof goes like:
Let GCD $( a+b, a-b ) = d$
and let there exist integers m and n such that $ a+b =md$  and $ a-b = nd.$
By adding and subtracting these two equations we get: $2a = (m+n)d$ and $2b = (m-n)d$
, because $a, b$ are coprime then $2$ GCD $(a,b)$ = GCD $(2a, 2b),$ and so on.

My question is, why do we have to add and subtract above equations? I need to understand the concept of this prove in some more details.
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  You don't have to add those two equations. There's lots of ways to proceed. You could, say mjust remark that $\gcd(a+b,a-b)=\gcd(a+b+a-b, a-b)=\gcd(2a, a-b)=\gcd(2,a-b)$.

Comment: @lulu i m sure there are other methods but i am particularly trying to understand this method.

Comment: Well, what don't you understand?  They key point is that $d$ must be coprime with both $a$ and $b$...do you see how to show that?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1911456/589

Comment: Do you understand why if $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $a$ and it divides $b$ then it we divide $a+b$ and it will divide $a-b$.  And do you understand and something If $k$ divides $a$ then it will divide $a+b$ if and only if it divides $b$?  If you understand that this result is immediate.

Comment: We do it because $(a+b)+(a-b) = 2a$ is an expression entirely in terms of $a$ and $(a+b)-(a-b) =2b$ is an expression entirely in terms of $b$.  Anything that divides *both* $(a+b)$ and $(a-b)$ must divide the sum and the difference and that will allow us to conclude any factor that divides both must divide both the expressions entrirly in terms of $a$ or entirely in terms of $b$.

Answer (score 2):

Letting $(x,y)$ denote the gcd of $x$ and $y$, you have $(a,b)=1$ and want to show that $(a+b,a-b)=1 \text{ or }2$. As such, you begin by letting $d=(a+b,a-b)$ and observing that there exist $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$a+b=md \text{ and } a-b = nd.$$
If you add the above equations, you get $2a = (m+n)d$. If you subtract, you get $2b = (m-n)d$. This tells you that $d|2a$ and $d|2b$. As you note, $(2a,2b)=2(a,b)$. This implies that $(2a,2b)=2$. This means that $d=1$ or $d=2$ (since $d$ is a divisor of $2a$ and $2b$, we must have $d\leq(2a,2b)$).

To answer the question about why you add/subtract them, the answer is to isolate $a$ and $b$ on the LHS. This is what allows you to conclude that $d|2a$ and $d|2b$. As mentioned in one of the comments, you don't HAVE TO add/subtract (there are other ways to proceed), but that is why it was done in this case.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.