# Prove that $\{\gcd(10n-1,5n+6) : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}=\{1,13\}$?

Tags: proof-writing, gcd-and-lcm

So I started with
$gcd(10n-1,5n+6)$ States that $d|(10n-1,5n+6)$ Which also implies that $d|10n-1$
and $d|5n+6$. Now I dont know how to show gcd of equals to 1 or 13.

Comment: $$\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a,2b-a) = \gcd(a,13) \in \{1,13\} $$ since $13$ is a prime number. If $n\equiv 4\pmod{13}$, $13\mid(10n-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

So, $d$ must divide $$2(5n+6)-(10n-1)$$

The basic idea is to eliminate $n$ from the relation to find a constant as [dividend](http://www.math-only-math.com/dividend-divisor-quotient-and-remainder.html).

Comment: Yes than how to show gcd equals 13,1?

Comment: @Kiterunner, So $d$ must divide $13$. What are the positive divisors of $$13?$$

Comment: @Kiterunner, Simplify $$2(5n+6)-(10n-1)$$

Comment: Woh Nice one,,Can you tell me how does one figure out what you have to do..Not this simplification but from 10n-1,5n+6 how do you get What has t be done?

Comment: @Kiterunner, Look at the last line of the answer.  See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852554/find-all-the-numbers-n-such-that-frac12n-610n-3-cant-be-reduced/1852765#1852765

Answer (score 0):

Use that $(a,b)=(b, a-b).$

Then  we have

$$
(10n-1,5n+6)=(5n+6,5n-7)=(5n-7,13)=13 \text{ or } =1.
$$